# How to get all users in firebase-admin api

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-admin

How can I retrieve all authenticated users in my firebase project using the admin api?

```
admin.auth().getAllUsers()
```

as far as I understand this doesn't exist.
So, unless I know the user's uid (by storing it in my database) I can't find the authenticated users.

I'm basically trying to purge user that did not complete the full sign up process (ie, creating objects in my database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is currently not available in the Admin SDK. You will need to use the CLI SDK to download all users:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#authexport

Comment: Is there any plan to implement this in the future?